# Can anyone explain how to calculate AUC_DS, AUC_BW, and AUC_0 mentioned in this image?

Tags: auc

I know AUC is for binary classification, but in a paper, the authors seemingly used AUC_DS, AUC_BW, and AUC_0 to compare vector values, like

ground truth of one sample [3,2,1,0,1,2,3]

prediction value of the sample [8.1, 7.9, 7.3, 6.9, 7.5, 7.8, 8.6]

they compared ground truth values and prediction values for many samples and gave a score.
[image: Paragraph from paper]
Can anyone explain how to calculate AUC_DS, AUC_BW, and AUC_0? Thank you.

Comment: Can you tell us which paper this is ?

Comment: The title is "Encoding Visual Sensitivity by MaxPol Convolution Filters for Image Sharpness Assessment" The preprint can be found here
https://arxiv.org/pdf/1808.00617.pdf